# Is there a cross-plaform method to convert from local time to UTC?

Tags: delphi

How to convert from local time to UTC on all platforms (Android/iOS/Mac/Windows)? On windows I use this function:

```
function AlLocalDateTimeToGMTDateTime(Const aLocalDateTime: TDateTime): TdateTime;

  {--------------------------------------------}
  function InternalCalcTimeZoneBias : TDateTime;
  const Time_Zone_ID_DayLight = 2;
  var TZI: TTimeZoneInformation;
      TZIResult: Integer;
      aBias : Integer;
  begin
    TZIResult := GetTimeZoneInformation(TZI);
    if TZIResult = -1 then Result := 0
    else begin
      if TZIResult = Time_Zone_ID_DayLight then aBias := TZI.Bias + TZI.DayLightBias
      else aBias := TZI.Bias + TZI.StandardBias;
      Result := EncodeTime(Abs(aBias) div 60, Abs(aBias) mod 60, 0, 0);
      if aBias < 0 then Result := -Result;
    end;
  end;

begin
  Result := aLocalDateTime + InternalCalcTimeZoneBias;
end;
```

Is there a cross-platform equivalent that I can use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call [`TTimeZone.ToUniversalTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.TTimeZone.ToUniversalTime) from the [`System.DateUtils`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils) unit. In the opposite direction you use [`TTimeZone.ToLocalTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.TTimeZone.ToLocalTime). Not only can you throw away your existing code, you can replace it with a single cross-platform function call.

It would be a prudent move to familiarise yourself with this unit.